'input-file' and 'output-file' vs. 'source-file' and 'target-file' as generic names
When documenting command-line things, it is often necessary to use generic names.
Sometimes I use input and output words, and they play nice:
# example 1
pandoc input_file.md -o output_file.htm

But sometimes they don't play nice, and I use source and target instead:
# example 2
mv source_file.txt target_folder/

I have two questions here.
The first question is whether it is fine (from the side of English language, which is a foreign one for me, logic, etc.) to use source and target pair only? Is it correct to say that this pair of words is more versatile then input and output?
The second question is whether it is fine to use target when we don't use source? For example:
# example 3. ImageMagick will copy all the .jpg and .png files
# to target_folder, and then trim them there
magick mogrify -path target_folder/ -trim +repage *.(jpg|png)


What matters is to be consistent. I prefer source and destination or input and output. I'm not fond of target. But that's just me, and as long as you're consistent, the people consuming your documentation will understand what you're trying to say.

@JosephLarson Hello, Joseph. I would friendly argue that merely trying to be consistent and not following existing conventions, we will introduce our personal conventions, often for no reason, and this is not a good thing. For example, personally I wouldn't use source and destination because source and target has much wider use (at least in Unix and Unix-like world, though I'm not really sure).

The consumers of your documentation will understand what you're saying as long as you aren't crazy about it. If you prefer target, then use target. The fact that you care about whether your documentation consumers will understand means you'll apply enough thought to the process. You'll be fine.

When explaining programming it is often helpful to use "speaking" names, that is, names that explain the named object, just as you did. Meaningful names make it easier for the reader to understand their function and they are easier to remember than meaningless names.
Of course the name must describe the function accurately, or else it will lead to confusion.
Whether input/output or source/target are more appropriate will depend on the context. An input is something that is put into something, e.g. data, while a source is the origin of something, e.g. the file or folder from which the data is taken. So if your example describes a procedure that processes data and changes it, input and output seem more fitting. (When describing an oven, your input is dough, and your output is bread.) While if your example describes a procedure that takes data from somewhere and puts it elsewhere, source and target seem more appropriate. (When describing the production and distribution of bread, a bakery is a source of bread and the consumers are its targets.)
Looking at a dictionary will help you understand the English words and choose the appropriate ones. It is impossible for me to know which words are the best ones in your case, as I don't know the background for your writing. If you have difficulties choosing the right words after you consulted a dictionary, maybe ask in https://english.stackexchange.com, as that is no longer a writing problem but a linguistic one.
